# Dual core debugging with NXP LPC43xx using Keil IDE

Tags: debugging, ide, arm, keil, nxp-microcontroller

I am using the NXP LPC4357 which has an M4 and M0 core, more specifically I'm using the Keil MCB4300 development board. I have a demo application running on it, I am able to build it and run it on both cores.  The problem I have is not being able to hit breakpoints on the M0 core.  I am able to do it just fine on the M4 core, but code I know is being executed on the M0 core never triggers a breakpoint.  I have read here: https://host.lpcware.com/zh-hans/node/1105959 that in the debug settings on the M0 core "Reset after Connect" should be disabled.  I tried that, but it didn't work for me.

Here are my project settings:

M4 core:

[image: M4 Memory settings]

[image: M4 Debug settings]

M0 core:[image: M0 Memory Settings]

[image: M0 Debug settings]

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the JTAG of M0 adress on the second M0 project debugging options.

That means you should select 0BXXXXX on the last picture (4BXXXXX is the M4).